# How to count number of files available in a directory recursively in Python using rsync?

Tags: python, rsync, python-2.6

I want to count number of files recursively in a remote server path using rsync in Python? I tried it doing like this:

```
def find_remote_files(source, password):
    cmdline = ['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source]
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=devnull)
        try:
            for entry in proc.stdout:
                items = entry.strip().split(None, 4)
                if not items[0].startswith("d"):
                    yield lent(items[4])
            proc.wait()
        except:
            # On any exception, terminate process and re-raise exception.
            proc.terminate()
            proc.wait()
            raise
```

It works in a situation where I have less files. But in case if I have more than 3000 files the rsync will take a long time to store it in a list and again calculate the length. That's why, I wanted to know if there is a `rsync` command just to count the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a different approach using fabric, which is a great tool for executing remote commands.

```
from fabric.api import run, env  
env.host_string = 'example.org'
output = run('find /tmp -type f | wc -l')
num_files = int(output)
```

Now you have the number of files in your variable `num_files`. I was just using the `find` command to search for files recursively beginning at directory `/tmp`, and counted the returned lines with `wc -l`.

Comment: Where should I put the username and password of the host_string = 'example.org'?

Comment: just check out the documentation on fabric: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/ - you can provide host and user on the command line or in your `fabfile`. The password should not be used, since the normal approach is by using ssh keys without password.